# Windows Network Connection - bytes or packets?

Tags: windows, networking

This is something that has bothered me for a while. When you open your active Network Connection in Windows (Pre-Vista) and display the Status dialog, it will show you the IP, hours online etc and below the "nice" animation there is a display of either Transmitted and Received Bytes or Transmitted and Received Packets.

What determines which it chooses? Is it the network driver? Is it random? :)

Please enlighten me. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These statistics are **driver related**. It may change when you update your NIC driver.

[Microsoft Help and Support](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;296669&Product=winxp)

From the website:

> The statistics that are displayed in the activity panel are adapter-specific statistics.
>   These statistics are not a
>   function of the operating system. The
>   network interface vendor determines
>   what statistics to report on the
>   network interface.